# Gravitational Waves, Dipole Radiations and Momentum

Tags: general-relativity, momentum, gravitational-waves, dipole, multipole-expansion

I am trying to understand Gravitational Waves and and going through MTW's book. They state that there can be no dipole radiation because of the conservation of momentum but gravitational waves also carry momentum so the law of conservation of momentum itself doesn't appear valid for them masses themselves and should include the gravity...so what am I missing here?

Comment: There is a paper by Steve Carlip in which he discusses, among other things, the connection between conservation principles and why the lowest order [gravitational waves are quadrupole](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9909087)

Comment: I'll chime in that if you're not already a little familiar with general relativity, MTW is a tricky place to start. Hartle's Gravity is a good introduction (and has a few chapters on gravitational radiation). Maggiore's book on Gravitational Waves is pretty approachable too.